# Are there any known Chernoff/Hoeffding bounds for the case of "almost independence"?

Tags: pr.probability, randomized-algorithms

The usual statement of a Hoeffding bound (e.g. [https://sites.math.washington.edu/~morrow/335_17/ineq.pdf](https://sites.math.washington.edu/%7Emorrow/335_17/ineq.pdf)) requires independent random variables.

My question is: Do there exist bounds similar to Hoeffding's that apply in the case that, for Bernoulli R.V. $X_i$ for $i \in [n]$

$\Pr\left[\bigcap_{i}X_i\right] = \left(\prod_i \Pr[X_i]\right) + \delta$ for $\delta << 1$, maybe specifically for the case that $\delta$ is a negligible function on $n$?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know of one, but you could try following the proof to see what changes...should be okay if you can show $\mathbb{E} \prod_i e^{\lambda X_i} \approx \prod_i \mathbb{E} e^{\lambda X_i}$.

Comment: I agree. I figured I'd ask in case this work has already been done :) Thank you

Comment: Your setting is a bit similar to Jason's inequality. Did you try that one?